# Javascript spread operator. What's the difference between { ... obj } and obj

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm working on a react project, the code I inherited often refers to objects with the spread operator like this:

```
{ ...obj }
```

instead of just:

```
obj
```

Is there any actual difference between these two statements? Which is best practice in react/different situations?

Comment: First one is shallow copy of obj.

Comment: Using the spread operator you create a new, independent object that has the same properties as `obj`. Manipulating that new object will not have any impact on `obj`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They return identical objects in most cases. Of course when you do

```
let obj2 = { ...obj };
```

you are creating a (shallow) copy of the previous object, since you enumerate the properties of `obj` and add them to the new object `{}`.

The 'almost' is because only enumerable properties are handled by the spread operator.

Comment: "identical" is a bit misleading, the object prototypes could be different, and so could non-enumerable properties, only the own-enumerable properties are identical.